# JNCryptor not working, Cannot Resolve Symbol AES256JNCryptor

Tags: java, android, jncryptor

im using JNCryptor library,
but i got error "Cannot Resolve Symbol AES256JNCryptor"
[image: red font]

```
 JNCryptor cryptor = new AES256JNCryptor();
    byte[] plaintext = "Hello, World!".getBytes();
    String password = "secretsquirrel";

    try {
        byte[] ciphertext = cryptor.encryptData(plaintext, password.toCharArray());
    } catch (CryptorException e) {
        // Something went wrong
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

my android studio version 2.1.2

can you tell me where is the wrong ?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to import the class,
hover over and press alt + enter or copy and paste this :

```
import org.cryptonode.jncryptor.AES256JNCryptor;
```